# chrome app display issue on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome web app that runs well in Mac and Chromebooks, but not in Windows 10 OS. Here is the background.js file:

```
    chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function () {
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': 1024,
            'height': 744
        },
        'minWidth': 1024,
        'minHeight': 744,
        'maxWidth': 1440,
        'maxHeight': 1050,
        "resizable": true,
        'id': 'mainWindowId'
    });
});
```

Users complain of not being able to change the height of the app, even when the default bounds was reduced to 800x600 (i deployed a test version with bounds = 800x600), and part of the app is obscured in the vertical axis, even though their vertical resolution is greater than 744.
Perhaps they cannot vertically drag the app smaller due to the fact that the edge is off the screen.. don't know.

Anyone else with this issue?  Googling provides no help.

Comment: Why do you need the max size?

Comment: certain issues with divs that start to misbehave if the size gets too large.  Byproduct of using third party calendar plugin called fullCalendar.